# Find duplicate child nodes in XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML Document

```
<xml>
    <schedule orderno = "1">
           <item orderno = "1" />
           <item orderno = "2" />
           <item orderno = "3" />
           <item orderno = "2" />
    </schedule>
    <scool orderno = "2">
           <item orderno = "5" />
           <item orderno = "6" />
           <item orderno = "1" />
           <item orderno = "4" />
    </scool>
</xml>
```

I have inconsistent data in the xml file and need a xpath expression to get the duplicate.

The rule is that the attribute `@ordnerno` from `item` in each node `scool/schedule` must have an unique value. If I have `1` `2` `3` `2` in `schedule` the `@orderno` with the value `2` duplicate and inconsistent.

I use the XML linq expression library

```
XDocument.Parse(structure)
         .Descendants("item")
         .Attributes("orderno")
         .GroupBy(g => g.Value)
         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
```

My solution is suboptimal because it group all nodes, `schedule` and `scool`.

The output is `1` and `2` but in this case `1` is not expected.

How can I solve my problem ?

Comment: Why do you think XPath would be better?

Comment: ? i dont understand your answer.. the linq expression is like  xpath. i am building my xpath expression with linq, but the expression is not complete.

Comment: Ah.  What you've got isn't XPath, [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is a specific language for addressing parts of an XML document.  You're using LINQ to XML, so I'd suggest you remove references to XPath from the question if that's not what you actually want.

Comment: `//item[@orderno = preceding::item/@orderno]`

Comment: @splash58 your xpath expression is exactly the same as mine linq expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try group by item's parent too, something like this:

```
XDocument.Parse(xml)
         .Descendants("item")
         .GroupBy(x => new { x.Parent.Name, orderno = x.Attribute("orderno").Value } )
         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

**Update** to select nodes with duplicated `@orderno` on any nesting level:

```
XDocument.Parse(xml)
         .Root
         .XPathSelectElements("//*[@orderno]")
         .Cast<XElement>()
         .GroupBy(x => new { x.Parent, orderno = x.Attribute("orderno").Value })
         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
         .Dump();
```

Comment: i have found a new case in the Database.. the Expression know group the ordnerno from parent which is also an inconsistent case :(  i have edited the xml file in the question

Comment: @Mo_Code so you need to select parents with equal `orderno` too, right?

Comment: Exactly, i need to select parents with equal ordnerno too. Also i need to compare the parent nodes orderno ( schedule and scool ) too

Comment: @Mo_Code I guess it is a typo in parent elements attribute name and it should be orderno, not ord**n**erno (looks like redundant `n`)? If so, see updated answer. If no, tell me, I'll update answer according to `n` in parent's attribute name.

Comment: its orderno.. this was an mistake from me.. sry for that